# Are schemas in PostgreSQL physical objects?

Tags: postgresql, namespaces, schema, database-schema

I use schemas in PostgreSQL for organizing my huge accounting database. At the end of every year I make a reconcile process by creating a new schema for the next year.

Are the files of the new schema physically separated from the old schema? Or all schemas stored on the hard disk together?

This is a vital thing for me because at the end of every year I've huge tables with millions of records which means I'll call heavy queries soon (I didn't plan for it when I decided to choose PostgreSQL).

Comment: Why does it matter for that if the files are in different directories or not? Heavy queries will put load on your system, no matter what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Schemas are namespaces so they are a "logical" thing, not a physical thing.

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-file-layout.html) each table is represented as one (or more files) inside the directory corresponding to the *database* the table is created in. The namespaces (schemas) are **not** reflected in the physical database layout.

In general you shouldn't care about the storage of the database to begin with and your SQL queries will not know where the actual data is stored.

"millions" of rows is not considered "huge" these days. If you do run in performance problems, you will tune your query using e.g. indexes or by rewriting it to a more efficient solution. In rare cases [partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html) a table can help with really huge tables - but we are talking hundreds of millions or even billions of rows. With medium to small sized tables, partitioning usually doesn't help with performance.

Comment: Thank you @a_horse_with_no_name 

I already have hundreds of millions (sum of all schemas) which terrified me; I didn't plan for it.
As mentioned [in the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html) it seems partitioning will fix heavy queries issue because the users make queries on some years (schemas) more than others.

Comment: "hundreds of millions" refers to the rows in a **single** table, not in the whole database. And as I said: partitioning is not necessarily a performance tool. But without more details this is impossible to answer